# How to get width of the object on some simple white surface?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

For example I have a pen on white paper:

[image]

After I take a picture of a pen I would like to know what is the width of that object. Is there any way how can accomplish that? I need it to be just approximately. So, I would set a condition to user to take a picture of object so that object is exactly the same size as the camera sees it. So front and back end of pen would be barely seen on picture.

Is it now possible to somehow to know that width of pen? Can we take into the consideration how wide area can camera cover? That angle which camera covers.

I really don't know how to start so any suggestion would benefit a lot! :)

Comment: Well, you'd need to know how far away the object is from the camera...

Answer (score 0):

This realy depends on the background of the picture. 
If you have clear white background, there will be no problem interating over picture pixels and remembering the borders of the Pen. 
Depends on how much noise you expect on your pictures. Well every picture is just array of pixels ;)

And you will need some measurable unit... so let the user set one inch unit on the picture and you will get some approximate value.

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided in this image it is not possible to recover the width in millimeters, inch or something. The angle of the camera doesn't help, since there are infinite scenarios where the light reflected by an object can create the same image (matter of optics).

You need to have some form of scale which measures need to be known or you need to know the distance from the camera lens to object plane. I would therefore recommend you not to take the pictures on a white plane but on quadrille paper instead.